# Given an urn of $k$ distinct balls. Do $n$ drawings with replacement. What is the probability that every ball is drawn at least once?

Tags: probability

The space of outcomes is $k^n$ since for each of the drawings, there are $k$ outcomes. Deciding the numerator seems harder. Originally the problem was "What is the probability that every ball is not drawn at least once?", but it seems easier to think of the complement, all different balls drawn at least once. I am thinking of employing the stars and bars method, which gives that there are $\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$ different ways for each ball to come out at least once.

This gives the answer to my original question as $1- \dfrac{\dfrac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}}{k^n}$. I think this is the exact answer, but I'm not sure. In my notes, my teacher just did something fancy and said we just need it to be $\leq \frac{k (k-1)^n}{k^n}$. Can someone help explain what approximation my teacher made?

Comment: What was your teacher trying to do in your notes?

Comment: a standard approach would be to use the inclusion-exclusion principle, once you have it written down it may be possible to obtain such an estimate by neglecting some of the terms

Comment: @mm-aops Could you explain a little more what you mean? I tried doing inc-exc but got very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you write down the inclusion-exclusion principle then the number of ways in which a *given* ball is not drawn is $ {(k-1)^n}$. you have $k$ balls from which you can pick the one that's not drawn which gives you $ k(k-1)^n$ so you're done. the probability that *some* ball is not drawn is less than the sum of probabilities that the $i$-th ball is not drawn which according to our calculations is $$ \frac{k(k-1)^n}{k^n}$$ cause we divided over the total number of possibilities $k^n$

in fact it's not so much an inclusion-exclusion kind of argument the way it's written now. I was first thinking about computing the probability of the event {all balls are drawn}. Here it's just something like that: let $A_i$ denote the event [$i$-th ball was not drawn] and let $A$ denote the event [some ball was not drawn]. then $$A \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i$$
so
$$ P(A) \leq \sum_{1}^k P(A_i)$$
and 
$$ P(A_i) = \frac{(k-1)^n}{k^n} $$ which ends the argument

Comment: Thank you, but can you please show the inclusion exclusion step. The rest makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I ask, because it seems like just doing $(k-1)^n$ isn't inc-exc, but just the number of way to color $n$ balls with $k-1$ colors. Which is what we want, but it's not inc-exc as you say.

Comment: you're right, it's not inc-exc as I first thought it'd be done, I changed my mind before writing the answer

Comment: as an exercise you can get sharper estimates with inclusion-exclusion principle. you'd do something like $P(A) \leq \sum P(A_i) - \sum P(A_i \cap A_j) + \sum P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_l$

Comment: Cool! Thanks. Is there a way to see though how these estimates will converge to the exact solution given above? Are there any bounded rates with which they converge?

Comment: most likely, tho you'd have to calculate them for yourself and see, I don't know what those rates would be

Answer (score 0):

Let our $k$-element set be $K=\{1,2,3,\dots,k\}$. Let $N=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$.

Imagine that we have done $n$ draws. Let $f(i)$ be the ball drawn on the $i$-th trial. Then $f$ is a function from $N$ to $K$. We want the probability that the function $f$ is **onto**.

There are $k^n$ equally likely functions. The number of onto functions is $k!S(n,k)$, where $S(n,k)$ is the [Stirling Number of the Second Kind.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number_of_the_second_kind) There is a wide variety of recurrences for $S(n,k)$, but no simple closed form.

The required probability is therefore $\dfrac{k!S(n,k)}{k^n}$.